# Multiple parameters passed in WCF client don't work (even when WebMessageBodyStyle is Wrapped)

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, rest

Hi fellow StackOverflowers,

I've got a WCF service wrtten C# that i can succesfully consume from things like jquery.

I want to be able to consume it by adding a web service reference in C# and making calls in the code.   Everything was rosy, until I added multiple parameters.  When I try to call **any** Service method, I get this error:

> Operation 'GetStopNames' of contract 'IPublic' specifies multiple
>   request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements.
>   At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements.
>   Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property
>   on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

I googled and searched StackOverflow for ages, but everybody seemed to have their problem fixed by setting
`BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`
in the WebGet / WebInvoke attributes.

An example of one of my service methods in the interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet( BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
     , UriTemplate = "GetOperators?appKey={apk}"
     , RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
     , ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ResultList GetOperators(string apk);
```

Is there something wrong with this?

I'm simply calling

```
ServiceReference1.PublicClient c = new ServiceReference1.PublicClient();
c.GetOperators("XXX");
```

inside the client, and it's breaking on the second line.

Any ideas?  If there is any more data you need to help answer me, just add a comment :)

EDIT:
here are the excerpts of relevant bits from my Web.config files
http://pastebin.com/CyQNG6wk

EDIT:
shortcut to serviceContract that I linked in comments
http://pastebin.com/bvGmGtfd

I ended up switching to using WebApi but I'm keeping this question open since I'm still not sure why it was failing.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Operation 'GetStopNames' of contract 'IPublic'`?

Comment: there wouldn't really be a point.  It's really long and goes something like

    'public ResultList GetStopNames(string apk, string p)
    {
    .... lots of stuff...
     return some ResultList();
    }'

Comment: Is that operation also decorated with `[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  You mean inside the .svc.cs file? If so, no. I assumed that since the [ServiceContract] interface acts as an interface and specifies it I didn't have to do so. (I just tested and adding it there gives me a (405) error

Comment: I'm asking about the definition of the method in the interface. Can you post your whole [ServiceContract] interface? Not the implementation, only the interface.

Comment: May be related, but instead of using [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",...)], use [WebGet].

Comment: All the expected parameters should of the type string..

Answer (score 0):

```
     [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetOperators?appKey={apk}",
     BodyStyle =  WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
     ResultList GetOperators(string apk);
```

In the .svc file make sure Service="Developer_Portal.Public"

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem in GetStopNames. I assume it is Http Get (WebGet). Make sure all the parameters it accepts are defined in uri template
GetStopNames(string p1, string p2, string p3)

uri = "GetStopNames/{p1}/{p2}?param1={p3}" or GetStopNames?param1={p1}&param2={p2}&param1={p3}  or whatever combination

You cannot generate proxy for rest by adding service reference. Do you have soap based service with same interface also?